# Segmentation fault (11) with 7.0.5-1~dotdeb+8.1

Tags: php, linux

we are getting random Segmentation faults (11) using PHP 7.0.5-1~dotdeb+8.1 (apache2 2.4.10-10+deb8u4, libapache2-mod-php7.0 7.0.5-1~dotdeb+8.1, with mpm_prefork module).

[core:notice] [pid 17587] AH00052: child pid 18181 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[core:notice] [pid 17587] AH00052: child pid 21123 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[core:notice] [pid 17587] AH00052: child pid 21213 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

```
[New LWP 27562]

warning: .dynamic section for "/usr/lib/php/20151012/curl.so" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f35b8bfb0af in zend_declare_property_ex (ce=0x7f35b5811a40, name=0x7f35b8d3b8d1, property=0x7fffbdd793e8, access_type=0, doc_comment=0x7fffbdd79273)
    at /usr/src/builddir/Zend/zend_API.c:3643

warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
3643                            ce->default_properties_table = perealloc(ce->default_properties_table, sizeof(zval) * ce->default_properties_count, ce->type == ZEND_INTERNAL_CLASS);
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f35b8bfb0af in zend_declare_property_ex (ce=0x7f35b5811a40, name=0x7f35b8d3b8d1, property=0x7fffbdd793e8, access_type=0, doc_comment=0x7fffbdd79273)
    at /usr/src/builddir/Zend/zend_API.c:3643
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Any idea what cause the SIGSEGV? Thanks!

Comment: Just as a guess, I'd say the problem is perhaps a wrong library or version mismatch?

Comment: Thanks, I saw the warning but i don't think there is any connection between zend and curl.